Como sumar en excel respetando una condición
Hola tengo la siguiente tabla en excel.
Jugador Dia1 Dia2 Dia3 Dia4 ETC Total
La columna Jugador se colocan los nombres de los jugadores, los días se llenan con oro, plata o bronce según lo obtenido. Lo que necito es sumar el total de puntos obtenidos por jugador teniendo en cuenta que ORO vale 3, PLATA vale 2 y BRONCE vale 1. Se entiende?
Por ejemplo Juan saco asi.
Juan ORO ORO BRONCE PLATA 9 puntos.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

sí es posible prueba ingresando una formula como esta en la celda de total para cada jugador:
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:F2="ORO")*3 + (B2:F2="PLATA")*2 + (B2:E2="BRONCE")*1)
Esto lo que hace es revisar cúantas copas oro, plata, bronce hay en las celdas de días y sumar los puntos que da cada uno para dar el total. Entonces si hay 2 oro dará 6 + 1 plata dará 2 + 3 bronce dará 3 y la suma de eso será 11 que es los puntos que tiene, prueba adaptando esa fórmula a tu tabla, saludos!

Muchas gracias me sirvio.

@juandavisso si la respuesta te sirvio, aceptala...

Cristobal, no solemos responder preguntas que no demuestren que se intento algo...

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

@gbianchi a qué te refieres de demostrar intentar algo? Era una duda muy simple a la que ofrecí una formula que según indicó le sirvió. He usado ese tipo de formulas en incontables ocasiones, no entendí lo que habría que demostrar. Si llegara a necesitar más información se la podría dar sin problemas si la pide, sin embargo, al parecer le sirvió como se la dí. Muchas gracias de todas formas por su preocupación. Saludos

Tu respuesta es correcta.. Te aclaraba solamente que no respondemos preguntas que no demuestren que se intento algo.. intento sumar y no pudo por algun motivo.. la funcion no le funciono...

La respuesta que me dio Cristobal me aclaro muchas dudas además de resolverme el problema en cuestión.  Como ven soy nuevo en este sitio y si no me maneje como corresponde lo lamento no fue intencional. También hace poco retome a usar Excel seriamente  unos 20 años diría y todo me parece mas complejo que antes. Igualmente si intente resolver este problema antes de pedir ayuda acá. Muchas gracias a todos.
